# Entity Framework 7 Core - automatic migration (and SQLite)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite

At this time EF 7 allow automigration from code?
Not from command line.

I found samples, but not working. Only database with table "_Migrations" created.

Main.dll (Application)

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlite()
    .AddDbContext<DB>(x => 
    {
        x.UseSqlite("");
    });
}

public void Configure(...)
{
    //Migrate
    using (var client = serviceProvider.GetService<DB>())
    {
        client.Database.Migrate();
    }
}
```

Shared.dll (DbContext & models)

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(
            optionsBuilder.Options.FindExtension<Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.SqliteOptionsExtension>().ConnectionString,
            sqlOptions => sqlOptions
                .MigrationsAssembly("Shared")
                .MigrationsHistoryTable("_Migrations"));
}
```